# no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "character"

Tags: if-statement, filter, using

I got this error when I try to run this piece of code in R

Error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "character"

R code:

`# Filter data if(analysis == "Sol"){ data.df \<- data.df\[tolower(data.df$Test) %in% c("sol","con/sol"),\] prefix \<- "S\_"`

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you

I am trying to filter my data base